# Regular expression to match specific word in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

I have this type of log file:

```
182.236.164.11 - - [04/Mar/2019:18:20:56] "GET /cart.do?action=addtocart&itemId=EST-15&productId=BS-AG-G09&JSESSIONID=SD6SL8FF10ADFF53101 HTTP 1.1" 200 2252 "http://www.buttercupgames.com/oldlink?itemId=EST-15" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5" 506
```

I am trying to create a regular expression to only match the word Intel, regardless of the relative position of the string.

I have come up with this regular expression:

```
^[^;\n]*;\s+
```

But it doesn't always work as it will match other strings as well.

I want to match the string Intel only so as to create a field in Splunk.

Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: Your post isn't clear as to what do you want to do after matching the word `Intel`? For matching just intel `\bIntel\b` is good enough. Can you add some more context to your post?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to create fields in Splunk with only this specific string "Intel".

Answer (score 0):

This query will do what you say you want, although I don't see the value of it.  If you say more about what your end goal is then I might be able to provide a better answer.

```
index=foo "Intel" | rex "(?<Intel>Intel)"
```